# Cannot index date in Pandas Data Frame from read_csv

Tags: python, parsing, csv, pandas

I came across a problem today that I unable to solve.
I read a csv file using

```
mydata = pd.read_csv(file_name, header=0, sep=",", index_col=[0], parse_dates=True)
```

the CSV looks like:

```
2009-12-10,5,6,7,8,9  
2009-12-11,7,6,6,7,9
```

instead of getting an indexed dataframe i get the following output

```
print mydata

Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [2009-12-10,5,6,7,8,9 2009-12-11,7,6,6,7,9]
```

Please help!! I have been trying for 2 hours now!

Many thanks

Comment: Are you *sure* that's the csv? It looks like it has . instead of newline, perhaps try lineterminator='.'

Comment: can your provide output of `repr(open(file_name).read()[:50])`?

Answer (score 3):

I think your code works. Here's what I see:

The data:

```
import pandas as pd

data = """2009-12-10,5,6,7,8,9
2009-12-11,7,6,6,7,9"""
```

Read the data from the csv.

```
ts = pd.read_csv(pd.io.parsers.StringIO(data),
    names=['timepoint', 'a','b','c','d','e'],
    parse_dates=True,
    index_col=0)
```

That looks like this

```
In [59]: ts
Out[59]:
            a  b  c  d  e
timepoint
2009-12-10  5  6  7  8  9
2009-12-11  7  6  6  7  9
```

And the index is a time series

```
In [60]: ts.index
Out[60]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2009-12-10 00:00:00, 2009-12-11 00:00:00]
Length: 2, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Can you give this a try and post an update if you get different results?

*UPDATE:* In response to @prre72's comment regarding column headers in the csv file:

If the csv has 5 column headers with the index column being unlabeled, you can do this:

```
In [17]: 
data = """"a","b","c","d","e"
2009-12-10,5,6,7,8,9
2009-12-11,7,6,6,7,9"""

ts = pd.read_csv(pd.io.parsers.StringIO(data),
    parse_dates=True,
    index_col=0)

In [18]: ts
Out[18]:
            a  b  c  d  e
2009-12-10  5  6  7  8  9
2009-12-11  7  6  6  7  9

In [19]: ts.index
Out[19]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2009-12-10 00:00:00, 2009-12-11 00:00:00]
Length: 2, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Comment: I have noticed a difference: your data has no headers, while my csv has headers in it with quoted names "". Should i remove headers when reading and then add them back?

Comment: Interesting. Does the 1st line of your csv have 5 or 6 headers in it? What I mean is, does the index column have a column header? Or does the file have only 5 column headers with the index column unlabeled?

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd
raw_dt = pd.read_csv("fileName.csv", import_dates = True, index_col = 0)
raw_dt
```

Now, when you execute this code, `index_col = 0` will treat the first column from your file as the index column and `import_dates = True` will parse columns containing dates in your file to date type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `parse_dates=[0]` to specify the date columns you want to parse. You don't have to sepcify `header=0`. Use `header=None` instead, which won't force you specifying headers. Try this:

```
mydata = pd.read_csv(file_name, header=None, sep=",", index_col=[0], 
    parse_dates=[0])
print mydata
            1  2  3  4  5
0                        
2009-12-10  5  6  7  8  9
2009-12-11  7  6  6  7  9
```

If you want to specify column names, just use this:

```
mydata.columns = list("abcde")  # list of column names
```